# Code is not executed in the order it is typed

Tags: java, multithreading

```
       Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            action = input.getText();
            action = erase(action);
            input.setText(action);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread Interrupted" + e);
        }
    }
};

        if(e.getSource() == call){
        if(!calling){
            String temp = input.getText();
            action = called(temp);
            input.setText(temp + "\n" + action);
            System.out.println(""+e.getActionCommand());
            calling = true;
        } else{
            calling = false;//executes
            String temp = input.getText();//does not execute until AFTER r.run();
            input.setText(temp + "\n" + "Hanging Up...");//does not execute until AFTER r.run();
            r.run();
          }
```

Im having trouble making this code show up on the GUI textArea (input) before the Thread.sleep(2000) occurs.

I need the textArea to display "hanging up" THEN execute the GUI lock/sleep for 2 seconds

Comment: r is a runnable object not a thread

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call directly the `run` method because it is not executed in a separate thread that way.
To start a thread, use `Thread.start(r)` where `r` is your `Runnable`.

You can give a try but this might not work either because Swing requires special concurrency management.
Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html